# What is $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} (-1)^{k}\frac{1}{k+2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Calculate

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} (-1)^{k}\frac{1}{k+2}$

Comment: Have you tried Stirling's formula to make the binomial coefficient asymptotically nicer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\frac{1}{k+2}=\int_{0}^{1}x^{k+1}\,dx$, we have:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k\frac{1}{k+2} = \int_{0}^{1}x(1-x)^n\,dx=\frac{\Gamma(2)\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(n+3)}=\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)} $$
and the limit is just zero. In order to avoid the Beta function, the identity:
$$ \int_{0}^{1} x(1-x)^n \,dx = \int_{0}^{1} x^n(1-x)\,dx = \frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+2} $$
is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Consider functions $f_n$:

$$f_n(x)=x^{-3-n}(x-1)^n$$

then:

$$f_n(x)=x^{-3-n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n \choose k}x^{n-k}(-1)^{k}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n \choose k}x^{-k-3}(-1)^{k}$$

Now note that:

$$\left(\frac{x^{-(k+2)}}{k+2}\right)'=-x^{-k-3}$$

So if you find antiderivative $F_n$ of $f_n$ ($F_n'=f_n$) you get:

$$F_{n}(x)=-\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n \choose k}(-1)^k\frac{x^{-k-2}}{k+2}$$

So:

$$F_{n}(1)=-\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n \choose k}(-1)^k\frac{1}{k+2}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\binom nk\frac1{k+2}=\frac{k+1}{(n+1)(n+2)}\binom{n+2}{k+2}$$

$$=\frac{k+2-1}{(n+1)(n+2)}\binom{n+2}{k+2}$$

$$=(k+2)\frac1{(n+1)(n+2)}\frac{(n+2)\cdot(n+1)!}{(k+2)\cdot(k+1)![n+1-(k+1)]!}-\frac1
{(n+1)(n+2)}\binom{n+2}{k+2}$$

$$=\frac1{(n+1)}\binom{n+1}{k+1}-\frac1{(n+1)(n+2)}\binom{n+2}{k+2}$$

$$\implies\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk\frac1{k+2}(-1)^k$$
$$=-\frac1{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n+1}{k+1}(-1)^{k+1}-\frac1{(n+1)(n+2)}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n+2}{k+2}(-1)^{k+2}$$

$$=-\frac1{n+1}\left[(1-1)^{n+1}-\binom{n+1}0(-1)^0\right]-\frac1{(n+1)(n+2)}\left[(1-1)^{n+2}-\binom{n+2}0(-1)^0-\binom{n+2}1(-1)^1\right]$$

Can you take it from here?